# Converting Netezza timestamp to Julian Day Number

Tags: date, netezza, julian-date

I have been looking for it during days but could not find how to do..

It is like:

`select to_number(to_char('2015-06-24 00:00:00','J'))` on Oracle.

I need to find the Julian Numeric Day value, not to be confused with the ordinal date of the year..

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "Julian". The current Julian Day Number is  2457203; it's the number of days since January 1, 4713 BCE ([reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day). The term is also (incorrectly) used to refer to the current day of the year.

Comment: I absolutely mean what you say by Julian. It is not 'YYYYDDD' like the other comment.

So, how could I do it?

Comment: Please update the question to include that information.

Comment: @tepples  Please do not do tag only edits until you have the reputation to make non suggested edits.

Comment: @NathanOliver Where is that documented?

Comment: @tepples It is part of the burninate procedure: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks. For my remaining questions, let's [get a room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82747/room-for-tepples-and-nathanoliver).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Conversion templates](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_ntz_sql_extns_templ_patterns_date_time_conv.html?lang=en) indicate that `'J'` is exactly what you want.

I think the issue you have is the `to_number()` function, not the `to_char()` function. Use casts instead.

```
SYSTEM(ADMIN)=> select to_char('2015-06-24 00:00:00'::timestamp,'J')::int;
 ?COLUMN?
----------
  2457198
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `DDD` (day of year) date identifier in TO_CHAR.

Reference: [date and time constants](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/c_dbuser_date_time_constants.html).

Comment: Thank you for comment but It is not what I meant. It is on the upper answers.